# Validate signature-message before request-body validation in Connexion

Tags: python, request, http-headers, openapi, connexion

Currently, I have a working API that uses Connexion and receives an OpenAPI specification:

```
connexion_app.add_api(
    "openapi.yaml",
    options={"swagger_ui": False},
    validate_responses=True,
    strict_validation=True,  # Changing this also didn't help
)
```

A response gets validated in the following order:

1. Check if API-Key is valid
2. Validate if the request body contains all necessary parameters
3. Validate message-signature
4. Handle request and send response

The verification of the API-Key is done via the OpenAPI spec:

```yaml
  securitySchemes:
    apiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: API-Key
      x-apikeyInfoFunc: server.security.check_api_key
security:
  - apiKeyAuth: []
```

The validation is also done via the OpenAPI spec.

The signature gets verified in the endpoint:

```
if not verify_signature(kwargs):
    abort(401, "Signature could not be verified")
```

Where `verify_signature` is basically this:

```
def verify_signature(request) -> bool:
    """Calculate the signature using the header and data."""
    signature = re.findall(r'"([A-Za-z0-9+/=]+)"', connexion.request.headers.get("Message-Signature", ""))
    created = re.findall(r"created=(\d+)", connexion.request.headers.get("Message-Signature", ""))
    if len(signature) == 0:
        abort(401, "No valid Signature found.")
    if len(created) == 0:
        abort(401, "No valid created timestamp found.")

    signature = signature[0]
    created = int(created[0])
    method, path, host, api_key, content_type = _get_attributes_from_request()
    message = create_signature_message(request["body"], created, method, path, host, api_key, content_type)
    recreated_signature = _encode_message(message)
    return recreated_signature == str(signature)
```

---

For security purposes I would like to swap 2. and 3.:

1. Check if API-Key is valid
2. Validate message-signature
3. Validate if the request body contains all necessary parameters
4. Handle request and send response

The problem is that Connexion validates the body before I get to my endpoint in which I execute my Python code such as `verify_signature`.

I tried adding the following to my OpenAPI.yaml:

```yaml
    signatureAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
      x-basicInfoFunc: server.security.verify_signature
security:
  - apiKeyAuth: []
    signatureAuth: []
```

But I think this is the wrong approach since I think this is only used as a simple verification method and I get the following error message:
`No authorization token provided`.

Now to my question:

**Is there a way to execute a function which receives the whole request that gets executed before Connexion validates the body?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the Connexion `before_request` annotation so it runs a function on a new request before validating the body. Here's an example that logs the headers and content:

```
import connexion
import logging
from flask import request

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
conn_app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__)

@conn_app.app.before_request
def before_request():
    for h in request.headers:
        logger.debug('header %s', h)
   logger.debug('data %s', request.get_data())
```