# Connexion request body parameter validation

Tags: python, json, connexion

This question is somewhat similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336502/validate-signature-message-before-request-body-validation-in-connexion) but I have a different use case.

We do our own validations on the logic we have in python, but it seems Connexion wants to do that for us.  I'm fine with it doing a JSON validation, but I don't want it to check if the parameters in the request body are correct or wrong because we have our own logic/logging we do for this.

Is there a way to change it so we can get validations to ignore the parameters by any chance?